# Finder Class php - search keywords issue

Tags: php, regex, wildcard, symfony-2.7

I am working on symfony 2.7 and i am using finder class of php.

I am searching more then 1 keyword in the list of files.

I don't have any idea how to search more then 1 keyword using "contains" method of the finder class.

Below is my sample code.

```
$value = 'Leo Tiger';

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->in()->files()->contains($value);
```

My Concern is that i want to search "Leo" and "Tiger" both separately in diff files like elastic search will do.

How to use wildcard in finder method ?

I will really appreciate if anyone can help me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in comment to function **contains** the parameter $pattern can be (string or regexp). You can try use regex to find keywords Leo or Tiger:

```
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->in($dir)->files()->contains('/Leo|Tiger/');
```